# SQL WHERE condition does not work with UUID

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple update query which is not working when I use a UUID in the `WHERE` condition.

Query:

```
UPDATE users
SET name = 'abcd'
WHERE userid = '73a01412-824f-11e3-a26d-94de804e5063';
```

But the following code snippets are working fine:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE userid='73a01412-824f-11e3-a26d-94de804e5063';

UPDATE users
SET name='abcd'
WHERE id=1;
```

The table looks like

```
CREATE TABLE users (
   id int(10) unique primary key autoincrement,
   userid varchar(100), 
   name varchar(150), 
   emailid varchar(100), 
   password varchar(45),
   salt varchar(45), 
   new_password varchar(45), 
   is_email_validated tinyint(1), 
   auth_key varchar(100), 
   email_auth_key varchar(100), 
   is_active tinyint(1), 
   last_logged_in datetime, 
   created_on datetime, 
   updated_on datetime, 
   gcmkey varchar(500));
```

Comment: Which RDBMS? Is autocommit on?

Comment: Better post in sqlfiddle.com

Comment: please show the table definition

Comment: Table: users
Columns:
id int(10) UN PK AI
userid varchar(100) 
name varchar(150) 
emailid varchar(100) 
password varchar(45) 
salt varchar(45) 
new_password varchar(45) 
is_email_validated tinyint(1) 
auth_key varchar(100) 
email_auth_key varchar(100) 
is_active tinyint(1) 
last_logged_in datetime 
created_on datetime 
updated_on datetime 
gcmkey varchar(500)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson  : Mysql is the RDBMS and autocommit is off

Comment: Is there any error msg while updating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't be the case. I tried the same update statement in MySQL and it worked fine

```
UPDATE users
SET name = 'abcd'
WHERE userid = '73a01412-824f-11e3-a26d-94de804e5063';
```

See the sample fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23101/1

Comment: It was the problem with my mysql workbench